# Sequelize doesn't create foreign keys as constraints in the database

Tags: mysql, node.js, foreign-keys, sequelize-cli

I am working on a small project to understand how an web application works and i have installed sequelize-cli along with mysql2 modules.

I generated a model with the CLI in terminal and it gave me a model, to which I made this changes:-

author.js:

```
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Author extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      Author.hasMany(models.Book,{foreignKey:'authorId'})
    }
  }
  Author.init({
    name: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'Author',
  });
  return Author;
};
```

user.js:

```
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class User extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      User.belongsTo(models.Book, {
        foreignKey: 'id'
      });
    }
  }
  User.init({
    first_name: DataTypes.STRING,
    last_name: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'User',
  });
  return User;
};
```

and finally book.js

```
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Book extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      Book.belongsTo(models.Author, { foreignKey: 'id' });
      Book.hasOne(models.User);
    }
  }
  Book.init({
    authorId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    stock: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    user_id: DataTypes.INTEGER
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'Book',
  });
  return Book;
};
```

after that, when i ran db:migrate, it created an id of each models and the models are generated in the database,except there is no foreign keys generated in the database by checking it on MySQL Workbench.

I do understand that I am either missing a step or I am doing something wrong, but I cannot figure out what it is.